Anti-isomorphism on sublattice
Let $L$ be a relatively complemented modular lattice with no infinite chains. Let $a\in L$ and consider the sublattice $A = [0_L,a]\subseteq L$. Let $\zeta\colon L \rightarrow L$ be an anti-isomorphism. Can one then construct an anti-isomorphism $\tau \colon A \rightarrow A$ such that $\tau(V) = a \wedge \zeta(V)$ for all $V\leq a$? This can clearly be done on a subspace lattice on a finite-dimensional vector space over a finite field, but is it a general property? Maybe some of the assumptions on $L$ can be loosened as well.
